# MobileService Publish does not change the Mobileservice

Tags: .net, azure, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I have a mobileservice up and running, but suddenly one function stopped getting updated when I publish, and I get no errors. Other than when I want to contact it.

The code for the function was:

```
[Route("api/Game/GetCurGame")]
    [AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.User)]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCurGame(DTO.returnGameFoundData search)
    {
        Services.Log.Info("GetCurGame Function");
        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            try
            {
                DTO.returnGameFoundData ret = new DTO.returnGameFoundData() { playersTurn = true, gameID = search.gameID, NavigationParameter = 1 };
                //Services.Log.Info("GetCurGame Function");
                return Ok(ret);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                DTO.returnGameFoundData ret = new DTO.returnGameFoundData() { playersTurn = false, gameID = search.gameID, NavigationParameter = -1 };
                return Ok(ret);
            }
        }
    }
```

So very simple in the log I only got/get:
[image]
And on my client ( windows phone 8.1)  I get the error:

> Method not allowed.

Not knowing the error I changed the code, with more logs, and changed the first log to "AWESOME". Publishing the mobile service, success, and get a smiley face mobile service running.

But, the log is the same and the error is the same. Eventhough I changed the log code `Services.Log.Info("GetCurGame Function");` to `Services.Log.Info("AWESOME");`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best things you can do is to check out Kudu for the site.  This is sitting at https://<your-mobile-site>.scm.azure-mobile.net - it contains a lot of diagnostic information that you can use to see if your mobile site is being deployed.  Log into the azure portal first, then go to the Kudu site.

Also, I recommend installing some sort of JSON pretty printer.  I use JSONFormatter with Google Chrome for this - it's available via the Chrome Store.